# How to use difference in mean team weight to predict winner of college football game

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence

I think I need a new statistic.
I am trying to make the case that the average weight difference between college football teams is related to won-loss record. I am studying the Big 10 and Big 12 conferences where I take one conference at a time  and organize all their 2014 season's games into two groups (columns)- "Won Games" and "Lost Games" with the variables of each column being the weight difference between the opponents for each game. My concern is that these variables are not independent of each other since each loser's weight delta will be the negative of the winner's delta value in the Won Games column. Since the study involves the entire population and not a sample I'm wondering whether t-Tests and ANOVA are even appropriate in this case. But I need some test that will confer legitimacy on my hypothesis.

I have thought of using winners from the Big 10 and losers from the Big 12 which would provide two groups of independent data but would miss differences in the weight effect between the two conferences.

Any ideas?

*After further investigation I have decided to use the Z test which merely tests the difference between two means. The ANOVA is not applicable here since it is used when the number of means > 2*

Comment: The Z test tests the difference between two means given that you know the variances.  Why not t?

Comment: Actually, after more thought it occurred to me that this problem is a classic example of a paired sample t-test where each game is a sample where the team average weight of the winner is compared to the average team weight of the loser. Therefor the column of variable 1 will be all team weights of the team who won the games and column 2 will be the team weight of the corresponding opponent team who lost the game. Oh yeah. Dat be some BAAAD statistics, Mama